# React: How to add a button click handler to reveal text?

Tags: reactjs, handler

I want create a button click handler to reveal the answer text "Animal". So far I have `<button onClick={this.revealAnswer}>Reveal answer</button>` and the handler
`revealAnswer = () => { };`
What information should I put in the handler?

Comment: please put all your code

Answer (score 0):

Use the useState hook.

```
const [reveal, setReveal] = useState(false);

const revealAnswer = () => {
    setReveal(reveal => !reveal)
}

...

return (
    ...
    {reveal && text}
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a state variable (boolean type) to the component, something like `const [revealAnswer, setRevealAnswer] = useState(false)`. Here, 'false' being the default value.

In the handler, you can then update the state every time the button gets clicked.

```
const revealAnswer = () => { 
   setRevealAnswer(!revealAnswer);
};
```

And in your JSX you should have condition based on this variable `revealAnswer`.  Eg:

```
...
{ revealAnswer && textValue }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).